# When adding class in DefaultListModel, did it save the value of toString or the entire class?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

Newbie here.

When I added an element in the DefaultListModel, I used a class with an overriden toString.
Based on the sample code below, I want to display the selected item's ID when I click the button btnid.

The commands under displayID doesn't seem to work. Help please. Thanks!

```
class SomeClass {
JFrame f = new JFrame("Sample");
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
JList lst = new JList(dlm);

public SomeClass() {
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton btnadd = new JButton("Add");
    JButton btnid = new JButton("View ID");

    Container p = f.getContentPane();
    sp.getViewport().add(lst,null);    

    p.add(sp, BorderLayout.WEST);
    p.add(btnadd, BorderLayout.EAST);
    p.add(btnid, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    btnadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          dlm.addElement(new ElementDisplay(dlm.getSize(),"Element " + dlm.getSize()));  
      }
    });

    btnid.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          displayID();
      }
    });

  f.pack();
  f.setVisible(true);    
 }

private void displayID() {
    ElementDisplay ed;

    ed = dlm.getElementAt(lst.getSelectedIndex());    

    System.out.println(ed.elementID);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
}


class ElementDisplay {
    public int elementID;
    private String elementDescription;

    public ElementDisplay(int pid, String pdesc) {
        elementID=pid;     
        elementDescription=pdesc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return elementDescription;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. What makes you think it doesn't work? You need to actually have an item selected in the list for the button press to work, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Instead of depending on a button press, just add a listener to the `JList`. That way only when the item in the `JList` is selected, does it print. No need for the button and trying to avoid the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

```
 lst.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

     @Override
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
         if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
              JList list = (JList)e.getSource();
              DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
              ElementDisplay ed = (ElementDisplay) model.getElementAt(lst.getSelectedIndex());
              System.out.println(ed.elementID);
         }
     }
 });
```

---

See [How to Write Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) where you will run into possible listeners you can use for different components. As GUIs are event driven, you should take time to learn most of them.

Comment: it worked thanks! is it really necessary to create another JList and DefaultListModel for it to work? that is the only difference from my solution.

Comment: You're not creating another `JList` _or_ `DefaultListModel`. You're just getting the reference. A new object is _only_ created with the `new` keyword. The way I'm doing it is the proper way to do it. That way you don't need the `JList` or `DefualtListModel` as class members. You can just declare them in the constructor. Don't have to worry about scopes. The less data fields, the better.

Comment: The same way you're getting the reference `ElementDisplay ed`, that what I did with the `JList` and `DefaultListModel`